# Document AI: 400 Request contains an invalid argument The return of the beast

Tags: python, cloud-document-ai

This code raises the 400 error without details:

```
from google.api_core.client_options import ClientOptions
from google.cloud import documentai

from PIL import Image

from io import BytesIO
from base64 import b64encode


def get_image(file_path: str) -> Image:
    original_image = Image.open(file_path)
    original_image.thumbnail((round(original_image.size[0] * .3), round(original_image.size[1] * .3)))
    buffer = BytesIO()
    original_image.save(buffer, "JPEG", optimize = True)
    return b64encode(buffer.getvalue())

def read_text(location: str, file_path: str, processor_display_name: str):
    image_content = get_image(file_path)

    # You must set the `api_endpoint`if you use a location other than "us".
    opts = ClientOptions(api_endpoint = f"{location}-documentai.googleapis.com")

    client = documentai.DocumentProcessorServiceClient(client_options = opts)

    # Refer to https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/file-types for supported file types
    # Load binary data
    raw_document = documentai.RawDocument(content = image_content, mime_type = 'image/jpeg')

    # For more information: https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/ProcessOptions
    # Optional: Additional configurations for processing.
    process_options = documentai.ProcessOptions(
        # Process only specific pages
        individual_page_selector = documentai.ProcessOptions.IndividualPageSelector(pages = [1])
    )

    # Configure the process request
    request = documentai.ProcessRequest(
        name = processor_display_name,
        raw_document = raw_document,
        process_options = process_options,
    )

    result = client.process_document(request = request)

    # For a full list of `Document` object attributes, reference this page:
    # https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/Document
    document = result.document

    # Read the text recognition output from the processor
    print("The document contains the following text:")
    print(document.text)

read_text("us", "./images/SSP20170525_615.ARW.jpf", "paper-410817")
```

Like in other cases the error returns without details:

```
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
        status = StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT
        details = "Request contains an invalid argument."
        debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:Error received from peer ipv4:142.250.200.138:443 {created_time:"2024-01-12T14:38:57.43287462+00:00", grpc_status:3, grpc_message:"Request contains an invalid argument."}"
>
```

It fails with other images and other formats, opening the file directly without Pillow, etc

Can anyone point me where the error is?

Thanks